# What should be the result of the following SDT on input 0.110?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Consider the following grammar with corresponding synthesized attributes:

```
F -> .L  {    F.val = L.val    }
L -> LB  {    L.length = L.length`+ 1}{L.val = L.val + 2^ (-L.length) * B.val}
L -> B   {    L.length = 1, L.val = B.val/2}
B -> 0   {    B.val = 0}
B -> 1   {    B.val = 1}
```

If "F.val" gives the value of the binary fraction  generated by F in above grammar then, the value of F.val on input 
{0.110} is ____________.(3 decimal places)

The solution [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCoWk.png) says answer is 0.875. I want to know how are they calculating the L.value since 
we can see that when 
L.val = 0.75 , it should be actually 1  because:

```
L.value = L.value + 2^(- L.length) * B.val
        = 0.5 + 2^(-1)*1
        = 0.5 + 0.5
        = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L.length = L.length + 1
```

Writing the rules down like this is a bit ambiguous because `L` is used to refer to the parent node as well as the child node. In this case it is clear that the first L refers to the parent node and the second one to the child node (otherwise `L.length = L.length ...` would be infinitely recursive), but this isn't made explicit in the notation. To solve this ambiguity, we usually add indices to the child nodes, like this:

```
L -> L1 B  { L.length = L1.length + 1}
```

Now its explicit that `L` refers to the parent node and `L1` to the child node.

With that notation in mind, let's look at the rule that's relevant to the calculation:

```
L.val = L.val + 2 ^ (-L.length) * B.val
```

It's clear that the `L.val` after the equals sign must refer to `L1.val` because otherwise it'd be infinitely recursive again. But `L.length` could actually refer to either one. That is, the above could either be interpreted as:

```
L -> L1 B  { L.length = L1.length + 1} { L.val = L1.val + 2 ^ (-L1.length) * B.val }
```

or as:

```
L -> L1 B  { L.length = L1.length + 1} { L.val = L1.val + 2 ^ (-L.length) * B.val }
```

Using the former interpretation, `L1.length` is 1 and the calculation does indeed come out as `0.5 + 0.5 = 1`. However, using the latter interpretation, we get:

```
L.val = L1.val + 2 ^ (-L.length) * B.val
      = 0.5 + 2^-2 * 1
      = 0.5 + 0.25
      = 0.75
```

So the latter must be the intended interpretation.